# Multiple Persistent Units JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I have a Spring application, which is configured for multiple Persistent units.

```
    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list value-type="java.lang.String">
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/*-persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSources">
        <map>
            <entry key="dataSource" value-ref="dataSource" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="pm-model" />
</bean>
```

However, I'm getting an error on startup saying that one of the persistent units is not able to load.  I also called out in the code above to list all the persistence.xml files, but still getting the same error.

```
ERROR 2017-08-10 15:33:44,882 [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bService': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'com-model' is defined
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I'm all ears.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The bean named **com-model** is not found. Check this bean if created or not.

Comment: @MehrajMalik  I did find in the logs "No bean named 'community-model' is defined"  However, I have other persistent units that are fine using the same pattern.

Comment: you will need to show us what the com-model the error refers to is and where it is then, and what is different from those that are successfully using it and this configuration.

Comment: @jtoepfer I know it's an archaic question, but do you remember if you managed to solve it somehow?